# Visual Studio for MAC Publish to Azure - How to Change Users?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to publish to Azure but I want to switch to a different user.

Yet, the Publish Dialog only allows me to select previous users with no way to seemingly add a new user?

Is there some settings / file somewhere I can nuke to restart the dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the `Visual Studio` menu and select `Account...`, you can add multiple accounts.

Then, when you go to publish your Azure app, the dialog from your screenshot will present an option to select which account to use for publishing.